# React and React Router DOM - NavLink and Link aren't triggering API based OAuth flow

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building a pretty simple app so far that is using Node/Express server with basic API and React front end.

In Node/Express I'm using Passport so users can log in with Google which works 100%. However, only when using an `<a>` tag.

If I implement with `<NavLink>` or `<Link>` the address bar shows the updated URL `/auth/google`, but it does not trigger the flow.

Is there some gotchas in the react-router-dom lib in this case?

**Node/Express:  authRoutes.js**

```
const passport = require("passport");

module.exports = app => {
  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      scope: ["profile", "email"]
    })
  );

  app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect("/surveys");
    }
  );

  app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.send(req.user);
  });

  app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
};
```

**React client: setupProxy.js**

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy(["/api", "/auth/google"], { target: "http://localhost:5000" }));
};
```

`<NavLink>` and `<Link>` do not work for any of these routes that are directly accessed by the user: '/auth/google', '/api/current_user' or '/api/logout.' But when I use an `<a>` they all work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you show us the react part as well as back-end.
react-router-dom doesn't meant to send any GET request so you should probably handle it by fetch or axios or etc... with a simple `onClick` function.

```
<Link to="/anywhere" onClick={() => axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth/google")}>Google Login</Link>
```

Comment: I think it's because of the Router and an <a> tag should just be used because then it doesn't explicitly use the Router unless you have a matching Route.

Comment: react-router-dom is a virtual router you don't actually change pages when using it. the reason that <a> tag working just fine is because of it's normal behavior which is sending get requests.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @kianoosh has shared, react-router-dom's virtual router will only trigger Routes that are setup and everything else will just push a history state and not render a component.

So with...

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Inner>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
    </Inner>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you have a:

`<NavLink to="/another-link">Another Link</NavLink>`

It will push the history state to the stack but there's no matching Route for it to render a component for and therefor seem like it's doing nothing.

Non-matching routes to things like API endpoints defined in a Node/Express server will need to be triggered with a good old `<a>` tag.